# How do I create a new proccess in C# (.Net4)?

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to create a proccess that will run an executable (with paramerets) wait till it's finished and check for errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. `Process.Start()` will start a new process (with arguments, if you wish - there are several overloads), `Process.WaitForExit()` will wait for it to exit and the `ExitCode` property will return the exit code. All self-documenting, isn't it?

Comment: Don't forget the `ProcessStartInfo` class that can be used as an argument to create a `Process` object or to `ProcessStart`.

Answer (score 1):

> use ['System.Diagnostics.Process'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe", // filename
        Arguments = "/c shutdown /s /t 1", // arg
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit(); // or set timeout process.WaitForExit(5*60*1000); wait for 5min 
    var error_result = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error_result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[info] process created without any error.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[err] " + error_result + ".");
    }
}
```